# Should the evolution of SO's rules and culture be considered when marking questions as duplicates?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close, close-reasons, duplicate-answers

Today I came across a question that was marked as a duplicate of a question posted in 2012. The two questions were very similar, and the original question and answer was quite well upvoted, but it had several properties that made me think that if it had been posed in 2015 it probably wouldn't have been so well received:

- It was tagged with both [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) and [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b). It's arguable that it applied to both but still, this is one thing that gets newbies harshly downvoted
- It was a self-answer to promote the OP's library via an off-site link to GitHub
- The self-accepted answer contained no explanation of the code other than an explanation of how to call it

The question and answer may have been perfectly fine at the time they were both posted, and it looks to me like a good library. However, requests for library recommendations are supposed to be off-topic in questions, and I think it's reasonable to say that this applies to self-answers too, because the question is contrived to be answered with such a recommendation.

Separately from these reasons I don't think it was really a dupe, because the newer question asked for solutions pertaining to a specific special case that offers several optimization opportunities, whereas the original was a generic solution, however my main question is this:

When voting to close a question as a duplicate, should close voters be obliged to check over the original question to make sure that it conforms with SO's rules as of 2015?

I don't really agree with retro-actively purging old questions based on new standards (at least, not aggressively) but at the least I think that certain questions should no longer become valid for marking other questions as duplicates of them, if they are no longer good questions according to contemporary standards.

Answer (score 3):

No, dates really shouldn't come into play when looking at duplicates.  If the question is the same (or similar enough to be completely answered by the same answer), then the "rules" shouldn't matter.  A duplicate is a duplicate.

Closing as duplicate isn't even a rules thing.  It's not punishment and not intended to be a negative thing - it is supposed to be helpful to the OP because someone found an answer for them.  And for the site, it is a housekeeping thing to keep from having the same question each with the same or similar answer littering the site (or even worse, a really great answer on one of the similar questions and no one can find it since there are hundreds of duplicates).

So, it makes it easier to find answers to the same question regardless of when asked because the duplicates **should always point back to the question with the best answer** (note that I did not say "oldest" here - the answer quality should be the guide as to which is the duplicate target, so if a newer question comes along and gets a better answer before it is closed, the people should consider marking the older question a duplicate of the newer one).

> I don't really agree with retro-actively purging old questions based on new standards

If an older question is off-topic now, then it should be closed.  The age of it doesn't matter.  By leaving it, it will be a sign post to future users to say "hmmm, this tool request is here, so my question must be ok".... which only leads to whining and complaining on meta.

Likewise, if an answer that was acceptable in 2012 is the only answer, but it does not meet with the site's quality guidelines now, then it should be moderated appropriately (commented, downvoted, flagged, and/or deleted).  Usually a comment to improve the answer would be my first choice if the answer is salvageable by the author.

If the rules change in the future and such questions are considered on-topic again, then the question can be reopened.

Now if the newer question does not have the same answer, then it is probably not a duplicate, and none of this discussion would matter.

Comment: "I don't really agree with retro-actively purging old questions based on new standards *(at least, not aggressively)*": You cut off critical context. (That's my only quibble though...)

Comment: @Deduplicator Not meant as criticism.  I think it is actually relevant to the discussion.  I had that section in my answer in my original draft.  I only took note of that sentence in my 2nd re-read and added the quote to acknowledge the OP's concern - age of the question should never matter for any application of the site's moderation, be it duplicates, closure, etc.